What is important when relocating a server?
In the next days, our customer will make a relocation of their servers. Among these servers, there are two virtual machines of our project for which I am responsible for. Both VMs use the Linux OS; one is using Apache2 and MySQL, the other Tomcat6 and PostgreSQL. I am also using the same projects (both on a single VM at my side) while developing these projects. On my notebook, the VM is running in an Oracle VirtualBox environment.
The DNS at the customer side will be completely new, as the environment was built in parallel to the existing one with new hardware. The Linux VMs of our applications – one being a Web application – will now run in an Hyper-V environment.
What information should I prepare for such a relocation? What is important? What do I need to pay special attention to?
Is there anything to change in the settings of the VM concerning IP addresses?


It is FAR from clear what you are asking. If the DNS is "new" - this implies new DNS names - in which case this is NOT a relocation; it's a copy. There is a LOT missing from your question, walking you through the process of describing the problem correctly goes way beyond the scope of Q&A here. If the IP addresses on your local instance are impacting by this there is something VERY wrong with your development process.

If this really IS a relocation (i.e. public DNS will be repointed) then you need to MAY need to consider TTLs/fencing/bridging but that depends on the nature of the transactions.
